# Conditionally hide the nth element of a v-for loop without modifying the array. vue 3 composition api search function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a ref variable (`foxArticles` ), which holds a list that contains 100 items. In a v-for loop i loop over each value. As a result, i have 100 values rendered on the page.

```
<template>
  <div class="news_container">
    <div
      v-for="article in foxArticles"
      v-bind:key="article"
      class="article_single_cell"
    >
      <div
        class="news_box shadow   hover:bg-red-100 "
        v-if="containsKeyword(article, keywordInput)"
      >
        <div class="news_box_right">
          <div class="news_headline text-red-500">
            <a :href="article.url" target="_blank">
              {{ article.title }}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const foxArticles = ref([]);
</script>
```

I also have a search function, which returns the value, if it includes the passed in keyword. The function is used in the child of the v-for loop.

```
    <div class="search_input_container">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="search_input"
        v-model="keywordInput"
      />
    </div>

<script>
    const keywordInput = ref("");

function containsKeyword(article, keywordInput) {
  if (article.title.toLowerCase().includes(keywordInput.toLowerCase())) {
    return article;
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is, i can't  use .slice() on the `foxArticles` array in the v-for loop, because that screws up the search functionality, as it returns only the values from the sliced range.

How can i have the access the all of the values of the array, while not rendering all 100 of returned articles on the initial load?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach will make it incredibly complex to achieve. It would be simpler to always iterate over some set, this set is either filtered based on a search-term, or it will be the first 100 items.

I'm not very familiar yet with the Vue 3 composition api so I'll demonstrate with a regular (vue 2) component.

```
<template>
   <div class="news_container">
      <div
         v-for="article in matchingArticles"
         v-bind:key="article"
         class="article_single_cell"
       >
            ... news_box ... 
       </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    ... 
    computed: {
        matchingArticles() {
            var articles = this.foxArticles;
            if (this.keywordInput) {
                  articles = articles.filter(article => {
                      return this.containsKeyword(article, this.keywordInput)
                  })
            } else {
                 // we will limit the result to 100
                 articles = articles.slice(0, 100);
            }
            // you may want to always limit results to 100 
            // but i'll leave that up to you.
            return articles;
        }
    },

    ....
}
</script>
```

Another benefit is that the template does not need to worry about filtering results.

Comment: Since `foxArticles` is the main source you should be always filtering over it. Else you will lose the data you filtered.

Comment: Yes, foxArticles remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i kind of came up with another solution, for which you don't have to change the script part...

instead of having one v-for loop , you can make two of them, where each one is wrapped in a v-if statement div

The first v-if statement says, If the client has not used the search (keywordInput == ''), display articles in the range of (index, index)

The second one says = If the user has written something (keywordInput != ''), return those articles.

```
<template>
  <div class="news_container">
    <!-- if no search has been done -->
    <div v-if="keywordInput == ''">
      <div
        v-for="article in foxArticles.slice(0, 4)"
        v-bind:key="article"
        class="article_single_cell"
      >
        <div class="news_box shadow   hover:bg-red-100 ">
          <div class="news_box_right">
            <div class="news_headline text-red-500">
              <a :href="article.url" target="_blank">
                {{ article.title }}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- if searched something -->
    <div v-else-if="keywordInput != ''">
      <div
        v-for="article in foxArticles"
        v-bind:key="article"
        class="article_single_cell"
      >
        <div
          class="news_box shadow   hover:bg-red-100 "
          v-if="containsKeyword(article, keywordInput) && keywordInput != ''"
        >
          <div class="news_box_right">
            <div class="news_headline text-red-500">
              <a :href="article.url" target="_blank">
                {{ article.title }}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

im not sure how this impacts performance tho, but that's a problem for another day